# Can I make a left join in Python Polars with a column that has null values?

Tags: python-polars

I have data that is constantly changing and sometimes the column used to join two dataframes has only null values. Is there a way to do this in Polars? For instance, in Spark I used [EqSafeNull][1].

Example:

dataframe1 content

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |
| c | 3 |

dataframe2 content

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| null | 4 |
| null | 5 |
| null | 6 |

```
# This fails    
dataframe1.join(dataframe2, on="key", how="left")

Output:
*** exceptions.ComputeError: datatypes of join keys don't match
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not mixing vstack with a left join?

Comment: What version of polars are you using? Your example runs for me (on polars latest), I end up with a `value_right` column consisting of `null` values. Is that your intended result?

Comment: I've just updated my original answer. I am using polars==0.16.13

Comment: Oh right, so the actual `dtype` of the column is `null` - you can cast the type: `df2.with_columns(pl.col("key").cast(pl.Utf8))`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this and few people have put other valid solutions. This was my take:

```
dataframe2 = dataframe2.with_columns(pl.col("key").fill_null(pl.lit("null")))
```

It's probably not the nicest solution as there are chances to run into conflicts in the remote scenario that there's a real key call 'null'... but it gets me out of the error.

I have also found [this issue from 2022](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/2815). There seems to be more a decision from developers rather than a missing feature. I like the reason why this isn't allowed but it is not convenient. Either way, there's a way to move forward.

Comment: this is ugly and terrible, can't we really join using null as a value?

Answer (score 0):

The None/null values in a key column from dataframe1 match all rows with null values from dataframe2:

```
df_a = pl.DataFrame({"key": ["a","b", None], "value": [1, 2, 10]})
df_b = pl.DataFrame({"key": [None,"b", None], "other_val": [3, 4,  5]})
df_a.join(df_b, on="key", how="left")
```

If there is no matching key value in the column you used (on="key") there  is nothing to join.

**Edit**

To make sure df_a key olumn values are not Null:

```
df_a.filter(pl.col("key").is_not_null()).join(df_b, on="key", how="left")
```

Comment: It might not make sense on that specific example as there's nothing to join, however, this is to join ever-changing reports (i.e. dataframes) where most of the times have a foreign-key relationship but occasionally do not if that makes sense. I'd have prefer not to write some boilerplate code to figure out if the join can be done or not. Spark has that option with EqSafeNull.

Comment: @user18140022 The issue isn't EqSafeNull.  The issue is data types. You need to cast your key columns so they are matching dtypes. How are you creating these dataframes, from csv files? Is your key sometimes a Utf8 and sometimes an int or something?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor the key is always a string... when there's a key. In this case, there isn't and therefore is a null value. The reason I mentioned EqSafeNull is because I had to refactor this pipeline which was originally in Spark... and EqSafeNull worked fine.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no EqSafeNull equivalent in Polars join. Which means that when performing a join on dataframes in which at least one can have nothing but None values in the column you want to join on you must check this before joining or if desired change None/Nulls to "foobar".

Comment: @user18140022 strings can be null.  If you're loading these dfs from a format where polars has to infer the datatype then it isn't going to infer a column full of nulls is string, it's going to guess that they're floats.  Just do `df=pl.DataFrame({'a':[None, None, None], 'b':[1,2,3], 'c':['a','b','c']})` and then do `df.schema` to see what I mean